# Message getting expired in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: quarkus, activemq-artemis, microprofile, smallrye

I have created an ActiveMQ Artemis producer in Quarkus application using Eclipse microprofile emitter. But the messages are getting expired instantly, and being moved into `ExpiryQueue`. I am not sure about this behavior. Please suggest how could I persist message into the queue so that it expires only after specified time.

I am using below code.

```java
        @Inject
        @Channel("my-queue")
        Emitter<String> emitter;
```

Created below metedata:

```java
        String message = "my-message";
        OutgoingAmqpMetadata metadata = OutgoingAmqpMetadata.builder()
                    .withExpiryTime(10000L)
                    .withDurable(true)
                    .withMessageId(String.valueOf(message.hashCode()))
                    .build();
       
        emitter.send(Message.of(message, Metadata.of(metadata)));
```

I am using `smallrye-amqp` connector. Added below property in `application.properties`:

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.my-queue.connector=smallrye-amqp
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was able to persist message into the queue after your suggestion.

Comment: Also, I observed that the messages were getting lost if I restart the artemis broker. I fixed this by setting TTL withTtl(600000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're setting the wrong value in `withExpiryTime`. You're setting it like a TTL, but I believe it's an absolute time so you should so something like this:

```java
OutgoingAmqpMetadata metadata = OutgoingAmqpMetadata.builder()
            .withExpiryTime(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000L)
            .withDurable(true)
            .withMessageId(String.valueOf(message.hashCode()))
            .build();
```